# Error 1006 Support

Tags: error-handling, air, flash-cs5, helper

I am getting this error #1006 and dont know how to fix it. 
My code is:

```
firstrock.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,  r1Hit);
function r1Hit(e:Event):void{ 
if(firstrock.hitTestObject(player))
{   
    loser.visible = true;
}
```

}
it says that addEventListener is not a function. What do I do?

Comment: as mentioned in the other post, depends on what firstrock is.

Comment: i declared the firstrock to be a new object.

Comment: read this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html, first line:

The EventDispatcher class is the base class for all classes that dispatch events. The EventDispatcher class implements the IEventDispatcher interface and is the base class for the DisplayObject class. The EventDispatcher class allows any object on the display list to be an event target and as such, to use the methods of the IEventDispatcher interface.

Default objects (new Object();) implement almost nothing

Comment: Ok so if you couldnt already tell I am new to flash... Sooo what does that mean exactly?

Comment: its means that firstrock does not implement de addEventListener function. I suggest you start reading up on flash and actionscript, this is not something i can easily explain here.

Comment: can you explain what Ia should do to fix it? Ill read up on it after the error is gone.

Comment: i/we cannot fix it, unless we know what you want to achief. A simple solution would be to make sure that firstrock is of type eventDispatcher, but again i dont know what firstrock is

Comment: this is what I am doing. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLhPgtfCRWI the only difference is that rather than the mouse ending the game there is a square at the bottom of the stage that the user can move back and forth. When the player at the bottom hits any of the rocks I want the game to end.